# How to disable item from listview when he is clicked android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-contacts

I have dialog and inside the dialog I show contact name and email (with listview) from telephone. I want the user to choose a contact from listview and set the contact to edittext and when user click again this contact will be disable.

General user cant pick one contact from listview twice. My problem comes when I choose some contact and close dialog after that reopen dialog items on listview not reserves and can't disabled picked contact.

My xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/borderitem"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <CheckedTextView
       android:id="@+id/text1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
       android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:checkMark="@drawable/apptheme_btn_check_holo_light"
       android:paddingLeft="6dip"
       android:text="asd"
       android:paddingRight="6dip"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

.java file,

```
Button buttonPickContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contactact_us_btn);
        buttonPickContact.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                list.clear();
                populateList();
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor") @Override

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p_arg0, View p_arg1,
                            int p_arg2, long p_arg3) {


                        CheckedTextView checkText = (CheckedTextView) p_arg1
                                .findViewById(R.id.text1);
                        checkText.setChecked(!checkText.isChecked());
                        checkText.setPressed(true);
                    //Here i want to disable already picked contact




                    }

                });
            }
        });

private void populateList() {

        ContactsProvider cpro = new ContactsProvider(getApplicationContext());
        List<Contact> contacts = cpro.getContacts();
        for (Contact cnt : contacts) {
            // add all contacts in map
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // then put email and name of contacts in map
            map.put("name", cnt.name);
            map.put("email", cnt.email);
            list.add(map);
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View viewBox = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_listview, null);
        Button btn = (Button) viewBox.findViewById(R.id.mailsButton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setEmails();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReferFriend.this);
        builder.setView(viewBox);
        // dialog, with him create a window ,in this window show name and email
        // of contacts
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        listview = (ListView) viewBox.findViewById(R.id.listt);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set arrayList of disabled listItem's position and on each on item click put it's position to this array,then later in your adapter and in getView method you can check if array contain current position ,then disable it.
in your getView method

```
if(arrayList.contain(Object)position))
     //disable this row
```

and in onItem Click

```
 adapter.arrayList.put(position);
```